# Reverse Proxy through Apache2 for Odoo 11

Tags: dns, apache2, reverse-proxy, odoo-11

This is the script I've written in my .conf file of sites-available folder.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  erp.abclabs.com
    ProxyPass / http://35.134.151.156:8069/
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is what I've added in my /etc/hosts file.

```
35.134.151.156    erp.abclabs.com
127.0.0.1         localhost
```

Yet I'm not able to redirect the service to my domain name. I've also started the 'proxy' and 'proxy_http' service from the sites-enabled location.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you describe what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @DusanBajic What I want is that when I type the domain name "erp.abclabs.com" in the browser, it should redirect me to the IP address mentioned in my code above.

Comment: Is your code running on remote server on port 8069?

Answer (score 0):

Have you redirected the domain to this IP? I think Nginx is much better than Apache

Comment: I did. And I'm supposed to use only Apache here.

Comment: Is your service running? what is your log says?